# How do I include records in a Summary query to include those that don't have data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have a query on a transaction table that returns the Summarized total on a column for each ID based on a data range.   The query works great except it doesn't include those IDs that don't have data in the transaction table.  How can I include those IDs in my result filled with a zero total.   Here's a simplified version of my query.

```
SELECT tblID.IDName
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN tblTransactions.idxTransType = 30
                THEN CAST(tblTransactions.TimeAmount AS FLOAT) / 60.0
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'Vacation'
FROM tblTransactions
INNER JOIN tblTransTypes ON tblTransactions.idxTransType = tblTransTypes.IdxTransType
INNER JOIN tblID ON tblTransactions.idxID = tblID.IdxID
WHERE (tblTransactions.Deleted = 0)
    AND (tblTransactions.NotCurrent = 0)
    AND (tblTransactions.TransDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, 'March 1, 2018', 102))
    AND (tblTransactions.TransDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, 'April 11, 2018', 102))
GROUP BY tblID.IDName
```

Comment: Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Unfortunately a LEFT JOIN doesn't work.  I think it's because this is summarized data in the Transaction table and it can't include data that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's slightly more complicated than that:

```
SELECT        
    i.IDName, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.idxTransType = 30 THEN CAST(t.TimeAmount AS FLOAT) / 60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Vacation'
FROM
    tblID i
    LEFT JOIN tblTransactions t ON t.idxID = i.IdxID AND t.Deleted = 0 AND t.NotCurrent = 0 AND t.TransDate BETWEEN '20180301' AND '20180411'
    LEFT JOIN tblTransTypes tt ON tt.IdxTransType = t.idxTransType
GROUP BY 
    i.IDName;
```

Comment: That's better, although tblTransTypes is never used in the query so you may as well drop that line.

Answer (score 0):

You want `left join`s:

```
SELECT i.IDName, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.idxTransType = 30 THEN CAST(t.TimeAmount AS Float) / 60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS Vacation
FROM tblID i LEFT JOIN
     tblTransactions t
     ON t.idxID = i.IdxID AND
        t.Deleted = 0 AND 
        t.NotCurrent = 0 AND
        t.TransDate >= '2018-03-01' AND
        t.TransDate <= '2018-04-11'
     tblTransTypes tt
     ON t.idxTransType = tt.IdxTransType 
GROUP BY i.IDName;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- Use ISO/ANSI standard date formats.
- The filter conditions on all but the first table belong in the `ON` clauses.